# kernel mode scheduling - How It Works

Tags: multithreading

In the world of UserMode we have processes and threads.

We have a kernel scheduler that schedules the thread running times and that's how we get "multi threads".

Now I have a few questions:

1. In a situation where we have multiple processors, so we actually
   have the physical ability to really run a number of threads , how do
   the different processors know how to return to the scheduler? and
   how is "race condition" prevented?
2. Does the "process" concept exist in the kernel?
3. Does each driver have its own thread? (I mean, do we have a scheduler on drivers too, and everything works just like in UserMod
   in terms of scheduling?)
4. Does the kernel have its own thread? (Do we also have a scheduler on the kernel itself?)

Answer (score 1):

1. OSes will have a timer interrupt setup, usually at about 60ms. The interrupt handler in the OS will kick-off the scheduling algorithms, to see what's best run next. This is called preempting, because the OS does this without cooperation from the applications its running. Other interrupts - from devices - will also kick off a scheduling reevaluation. So when a new Ethernet frame is received, that may eventually result in your web browser being rescheduled resulting in a page being drawn. In the old days of Windows 3 and the like (and other early OSes of that sort), they depended on applications making calls to operating system functions to give the OS a chance to run the scheduling algorithms. This is called cooperative multi-tasking - the OS depends on the applications making those OS function calls.
2. Depends. A microkernel based OS will actually put a lot of what we think is OS code into processes (e.g. device drivers), and run them at no higher privilege than other userland applications. Windows and Linux aren't like this.
3. Again, depends. In Linux the drivers were simply functions that'd get run whenever, or if the Linux PreemptRT patch set was applied the bulk of this functionality was put into kernel threads, to be scheduled along with all other threads in the system. Kind of a poor man's way of getting a fully preemptable operating system. In OSes like VXWorks, the device drivers have always been threads with no more or less privilege than application threads (in fact VxWorks makes no distinction between them). This means that the whole of VxWorks is preemptable - even all the device drivers, etc - making it a very good hard real time OS.
4. The kernel is not a thread as such, as it's the thing that defines what a thread is. But it is code executing within the system.

Comment: 1. How we avoid race condition? (first processor get to scheduling algorithms pick the first to run second processor get to scheduling algorithms pick the first to run , then first remove the first to run already picked twice, and the second remove the second to run that nor the first or the second actually runs)

Comment: 4. How do we know how to jump to the scheduler? is it in a fix address? we do get interrupts in the middle of kernel work, if we don't thread it and schedule it how do we know where to return to?

Comment: @0xPwn, 1. It depends on the design of the kernel. A simple one might do all the scheduling evaluation in a single core, and the rest simply have to wait until that's completed. If it's a distributed scheduler, then the schedulers being run on each core would have to have some form of IPC (shared memory, mutex semaphores) in order to arrive at a consensus as to what should be run where.

Comment: @0xPwn, 3. I don't know.

Comment: @0xPwn, 4. We don't, if "we" means an application. The whole point of a preemptive OS is that it decides to intervene regardless of what our application is doing. If that application happens to make system calls to interact with things like semaphores, file I/O, etc. that is commonly used by OSes to reschedule application threads too. This makes sense; a bit of file I/O is likely to be a blocking operation, so the kernel may as well kick off the I/O requests to the underlying device and schedule other application threads in the meantime, waiting for the device to raise an interrupt when done.

Comment: @0xPwn, 4. Also, how the kernel deals with interrupts depends on design too. An Interrupt service routine might disable all interrupts until it has completed, reenabling them at the end. The interrupt hardware would then immediately raise the next interrupt if one had occurred in the meantime. Other designs like VXWorks are themselves fully preemptable, meaning they don’t even do that. Queues are commonly used to keep track of everything.

Comment: When interrupt happened  (lets say we in a system with timer interrupt of 60 ms, so timer interrupt happened) , how the core know which line of code to run? (where is the scheduler)   if it's not in some queue (i.e. thread) then the only other option is fixed address for the scheduler no?

Comment: @0xPwn, I suggest you read up about interrupt vectors: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_vector_table. The OS will configure the entry for the timer interrupt to point to one of its own interrupt service routines, and that'll be the one that either starts or does the whole of the scheduling reassessment.